# Django Template Data

Tags: django, templates

I have the following models:

```
class Contactnumber(TimeStampedModel):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(‘contacts.Contact')

class Contact(TimeStampedModel):
        contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True,
                               verbose_name='Contact Name')
        practice = models.ManyToManyField(‘practice.Practice’,
                                      related_name=“contacts",)



class Practice(TimeStampedModel):
       practice = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True,
                                verbose_name='Practice Name')
```

I have a template including data tables in which I want to show the following:
Practice, Contact, Contact Phone

The following gives me the contact for the practice:

```
{% for contact in practice.contacts.all %}
    {{ contact }}
    {% endfor %}
```

My question is how do  include the contact phone number as I seem a bit lost.
Any help would be appreciated. Apologies if this is a simple question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATM your contacts can have multiple phone numbers, so one way would be to do it like this:

```
{% for contact in practice.contacts.all %}
    {% for number in contact.contactnumber_set.all %}
        {{ number.phone_number }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The logic behing this is that when you haven't set a `related_name` to a relation field (one2one, FK, M2M), then you can access the related model by the model's name and adding "_set" to the end. So you iterate over all contacts and over all numbers that a contact has and the output will be all the numbers for those guys. Feel free to format it any way you like (adding commas, `<br>`'s and so on).